# Questions about troubleshooting phone

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question like this:

> Why won't my phone do X?

In my case, X=boot.

I have no idea what the problem is and if it's the device or OS. Where should I ask such questions? I know my phone has Android although I have no idea if the problem is with Android. I was thinking something like Super User or Android Enthusiasts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is off topic on [Super User](https://superuser.com). From their [help center](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic):

> Questions about electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones are off-topic (except when they interface with a computer).

Your question would appear to be on topic on [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/). From their [help center](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange is for enthusiasts, power users, and regular people who use the Android operating system.
>
> If your question generally covers...
>
> - Using your Android device
> - Using a particular app on your Android device
> - **Trying to solve an error or other issue in using your Android device**